# How to wait for a dispatch happening in one store from another store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I am using Flux from Facebook, react, ES6.

I'm having different problems with those singleton stores. However the recurring one is the following. I dispatch one action from one component and I have two stores (StoreA, StoreB) listening for that action.

My two stores are in two different files and in each, I export the singleton store instance. Both stores are already imported in their relevant container (a React component view). I want StoreA to wait for StoreB to finish processing the current dispatch, before starting the process in StoreA.

I have read the doc and there is the waitFor method that can be used with the token returned by the register method from the dispatcher. However my two stores are in different files. Cannot find a way to access StoreB's dispatch token from StoreA...

In other words:

ReactComp.js

```
...
handleClick() {
    dispatcher.dispatch({
        type: 'ACTION1'
    });
}
```

StoreA.js

```
class StoreA {
    constructor() {
        this.dispatchToken = dispatcher.register((action) => {
            switch(action.type) {
                case 'ACTION1':
                    // do something...
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

export default new StoreA();
```

StoreB.js

```
class StoreB {
    constructor() {
        dispatcher.register((action) => {
            switch(action.type) {
                case 'ACTION1':
                    dispatcher.waitFor([storeADispatchToken]); //how to get the dispatchToken from Store A... 
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

export default new StoreB();
```

I am new to the react and flux architecture, the answer could be obvious and sorry if it is, however with all the hours put into looking unsuccessfully for an answer, I am betting on SO..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import StoreA into StoreB and you should be able to reference the token:

```
import StoreA from 'path/to/StoreA.js';
// or if you're not using es6 imports:
// const StoreA = require('path/to/StoreA.js');

class StoreB {
  constructor() {
    dispatcher.register((action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'ACTION1':
          dispatcher.waitFor([StoreA.dispatchToken]);
          break;
        }
    });
  }
}

export default new StoreB();
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that both store files are imported in each of their respective component files already. If I do that and if I understand correctly, I would be duplicating StoreA right? I might end up with the previous instance I use in a component and the one I import in StoreB. Both will be listening to same actions which might end up in duplicating Ajax calls and other logic..

Comment: If I understand your concern correctly, the answer is no - there is only one instance of each store because you are exporting an instance from the store file, and not a class - ```export default new StoreA();``` - It's the use of `new` that's the key. StoreB and any components that use StoreA will all get the same instance when you `import StoreA from 'path/to/StoreA'`.

Comment: Yea so that is my concern but I is there a way around it? It seemed logical to me, to have one store per file. But because Flux is about singleton stores, I don't have access to those dispatch tokens if my stores are imported in different files. I found my self dispatching actions with in the payload the disptach token of the relative store. Don't think that s the right way to work with the Flux pattern. What if I had one file, stores.js, where I have: new StoreA() and new StoreB() somewhere in the file and do export default {storeA: StoreA, storeB: StoreB} ? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Andrea, think you misunderstood my response - you don't need to find a way around it - it sounds like you're misunderstanding how the export works. Because you are exporting an instance, StoreB and your components can all import StoreA as you have created it and will all get the same single instance, therefore there is no concern about duplicated action listeners or logic because that instance is only created once and is shared.

Comment: It is true that your current implementation isn't very 'flux'y in terms of the way you are dispatching actions directly from components - the usual approach is not to have components dispatch directly, but to do so via action creators - take a look at the Facebook flux demo Github project, and see how they structure it so that actions are dispatched only by modules in the actions directory - https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat/js

Comment: That all said, your suggestion of an aggregate store is an oft seen pattern - it's quite common to see a top level store that aggregates other stores, and for only the aggregate to be imported into the view layer, usually backing a top level view component. This allows you to keep all the synchronous waitFor logic in the aggregate and to then use React props to pass data to child components - basically ending up with only a single store import at the top of the view layer rather than loads of granular imports throughout your components.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I misunderstood you and how the export works...my bad. Thanks a lot!